# Is there a way other then union to merge 2 columns from 2 different tables as displayed in the pic. I was hoping if it's possible using unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image: Sample Data for reference]

The two tables are combined using JOIN and displayed in a view. MY MAIN REQUIREMENT IS MERGING THE TWO COLUMNS INTO ONE COMMON COLUMN

Comment: Text: OK. Screenshots: not acceptable. *Photos of screens*: come on. Also it's unclear what you've tried and what the problem with it is; please give a [mre] per [ask].

Comment: You have the text in notepad.  Use control C to copy it and control V to paste it into the question.  There is no reason to take a photo of your screen!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you don't want to use UNION in this case -- instead you use something called a join.  In your case it would look like this:

```
select Sno, EmpNo, SnNo 
from Employee e 
left join Test t on e.EmpNo = t.EmpNo
```

This would result in the following output

```
SNo EmpNo   SnNo
1   100     11
2   101     12
3   102     13
```

---

You can also concat the colums into one single column:

```
select EmpNo, SnNo || ' ' || Sno
from Employee e 
left join Test t on e.EmpNo = t.EmpNo
```

which will result in

```
EmpNo   SnNoSno
100     11  1
101     12  2
102     13  3
```

Comment: Hi, join have done what I am looking for is how to merge the two columns and get a single column without using union

Answer (score 0):

```
select srno as id,empnum as emplyno from employee
union all
select srnotest as id,testsrno as emplyno from test
```

You can also use union if you want like to remove duplicate